# Excel Vba - Excel crashes using Multipage with Texboxes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i used to have my UserForm in Excel without a Multipage and everthing worked fine until i had more Data, then i switched to a Multipage, i have TextBoxes and ComboBoxes that get filled by Cell Values when the UserForm Starts based on what i wrote in there before i saved it. Like i said everything worked fine until i used a Multipage.
i Tried to put it in the Initialize as well as in the Activation field.
Everytime when i open the Excel it doesnt give me an error, instead it shows an infinity Loading until i click the Form then it crashes and closes.
This is the Fill TextBoxes and ComboBoxes code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Worksheets("Daten").Activate
ComboBox1.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("H6")
ComboBox2.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J6")
ComboBox3.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J7")
ComboBox4.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J8")
ComboBox5.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J9")
 

TextBox1.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B12")
TextBox2.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C12")
TextBox3.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D12")
TextBox4.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E12")
TextBox5.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F12")
TextBox6.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J12")

TextBox7.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B13")
TextBox8.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C13")
TextBox9.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D13")
TextBox10.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E13")
TextBox11.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F13")
TextBox12.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J13")

TextBox13.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B14")
TextBox14.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C14")
TextBox15.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D14")
TextBox16.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E14")
TextBox17.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F14")
TextBox18.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J14")

TextBox19.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B15")
TextBox20.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C15")
TextBox21.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D15")
TextBox22.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E15")
TextBox23.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F15")
TextBox24.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J15")


TextBox25.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B16")
TextBox26.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C16")
TextBox27.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D16")
TextBox28.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E16")
TextBox29.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F16")
TextBox30.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J16")

TextBox31.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B17")
TextBox32.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C17")
TextBox33.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D17")
TextBox34.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E17")
TextBox35.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F17")
TextBox36.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J17")

TextBox37.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B18")
TextBox38.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C18")
TextBox39.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D18")
TextBox40.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E18")
TextBox41.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F18")
TextBox42.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J18")

TextBox43.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B19")
TextBox44.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C19")
TextBox45.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D19")
TextBox46.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E19")
TextBox47.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F19")
TextBox48.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J19")

TextBox49.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B20")
TextBox50.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C20")
TextBox51.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D20")
TextBox51.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E20")
TextBox53.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F20")
TextBox54.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J20")

TextBox55.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B21")
TextBox56.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C21")
TextBox57.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D21")
TextBox58.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E21")
TextBox59.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F21")
TextBox60.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J21")

TextBox61.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B22")
TextBox62.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C22")
TextBox63.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D22")
TextBox64.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E22")
TextBox65.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F22")
TextBox66.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J22")

TextBox67.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B23")
TextBox68.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C23")
TextBox69.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D23")
TextBox70.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E23")
TextBox71.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F23")
TextBox72.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J23")

TextBox73.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B24")
TextBox74.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C24")
TextBox75.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D24")
TextBox76.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E24")
TextBox77.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F24")
TextBox78.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J24")

TextBox79.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B25")
TextBox80.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C25")
TextBox81.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D25")
TextBox82.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E25")
TextBox83.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F25")
TextBox84.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J25")

TextBox85.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B26")
TextBox86.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C26")
TextBox87.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D26")
TextBox88.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E26")
TextBox89.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F26")
TextBox90.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J26")

TextBox91.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B27")
TextBox92.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C27")
TextBox93.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D27")
TextBox94.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E27")
TextBox95.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F27")
TextBox96.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J27")

TextBox97.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("B28")
TextBox98.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("C28")
TextBox99.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("D28")
TextBox100.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("E28")
TextBox101.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("F28")
TextBox102.Value = Sheets("Daten").Range("J28")


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))


Worksheets("SMT").Activate
TextBox105.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B12")
TextBox106.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C12")
TextBox107.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D12")
TextBox108.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E12")
TextBox109.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F12")
TextBox110.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J12")

TextBox111.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B13")
TextBox112.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C13")
TextBox113.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D13")
TextBox114.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E13")
TextBox115.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F13")
TextBox116.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J13")

TextBox117.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B14")
TextBox118.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C14")
TextBox119.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D14")
TextBox120.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E14")
TextBox121.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F14")
TextBox122.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J14")

TextBox123.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B15")
TextBox124.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C15")
TextBox125.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D15")
TextBox126.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E15")
TextBox127.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F15")
TextBox128.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J15")

TextBox129.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B16")
TextBox130.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C16")
TextBox131.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D16")
TextBox132.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E16")
TextBox133.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F16")
TextBox134.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J16")


TextBox135.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B17")
TextBox136.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C17")
TextBox137.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D17")
TextBox138.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E17")
TextBox139.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F17")
TextBox140.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J17")

TextBox141.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B18")
TextBox142.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C18")
TextBox143.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D18")
TextBox144.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E18")
TextBox145.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F18")
TextBox146.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J18")

TextBox147.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B19")
TextBox148.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C19")
TextBox149.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D19")
TextBox150.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E19")
TextBox151.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F19")
TextBox152.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J19")

TextBox153.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B20")
TextBox154.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C20")
TextBox155.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D20")
TextBox156.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E20")
TextBox157.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F20")
TextBox158.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J20")

TextBox159.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B21")
TextBox160.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C21")
TextBox161.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D21")
TextBox162.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E21")
TextBox163.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F21")
TextBox164.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J21")

TextBox165.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B22")
TextBox166.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C22")
TextBox167.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D22")
TextBox168.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E22")
TextBox169.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F22")
TextBox170.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J22")

TextBox171.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B23")
TextBox172.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C23")
TextBox173.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D23")
TextBox174.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E23")
TextBox175.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F23")
TextBox176.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J23")

TextBox177.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B24")
TextBox178.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C24")
TextBox179.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D24")
TextBox180.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E24")
TextBox181.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F24")
TextBox182.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J24")

TextBox183.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B25")
TextBox184.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C25")
TextBox185.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D25")
TextBox186.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E25")
TextBox187.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F25")
TextBox188.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J25")

TextBox189.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B26")
TextBox190.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C26")
TextBox191.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D26")
TextBox192.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E26")
TextBox193.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F26")
TextBox90.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J26")

TextBox194.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B27")
TextBox195.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C27")
TextBox196.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D27")
TextBox197.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E27")
TextBox198.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F27")
TextBox200.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J27")

TextBox201.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("B28")
TextBox202.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("C28")
TextBox203.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("D28")
TextBox204.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("E28")
TextBox205.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("F28")
TextBox206.Value = Sheets("SMT").Range("J28")
End Sub
```

If anyone could help me i would be thankfull!

i tried to delete the Multipage and it worked but using it didnt work.